# moving price block from catalog/product/view.phtml to catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1

i am moving this portion from catalog/product/view.phtml

```
...
        <div class="price-box-wrapper">
            <div class="product-type-data<?php echo $productTypeClasses; ?>"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data'); ?></div> 
        </div>  

        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml(); //tier prices ?>
...
```

to catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml

```
....
            <?php
                //CSS classes based on product type
                $productTypeId = $this->getProduct()->getTypeId();
                $productTypeClasses = '';
                if ($productTypeId === 'grouped') {
                    $productTypeClasses .= ' is-type-grouped';
                }
            ?>

            <div class="price-box-wrapper">
                <div class="product-type-data<?php echo $productTypeClasses; ?>"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data'); ?></div> 
            </div>  

            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml(); //tier prices ?>
```

How to get $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change reference block of `product_type_data`

- from: `product.info`
- to: `product.info.options.wrapper` / `product_options_wrapper`

Just like

```
   <PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
            <label>Catalog Product View (Grouped)</label>
            <reference name="product_options_wrapper"> 
<!--  product.info  to product_options_wrapper -->
```